# How to display damage dealt on Hud?

Tags: overwatch

In some Valve games ( CS, TF2 ... ) there is a feature that allows you to see how many damage you have dealt to an ennemy, And I was wondering if there is a similar mechanism in Overwatch.

Answer (score 7):

No, there is no way to display the amount of damage dealt as a number, but you can see the enemy's health bar above their head after damaging them once, and notice how it drops from each attack.